# WPF C# How to know if the value of a setting has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, settings

Let's say I have two bool settings named "Allow_X" and "Allow_Y" in the settings file of my application. When the user changes the value of either of the two settings I want my application to show a message box with the message containing the name of the setting that was changed, the value of the setting before the change and value of the setting once it has been changed? How do I do it?

Comment: The user can't modify the settings directly. You would provide some logic to read/write from/to the settings. For example, this could be the Checked/Unchecked event handlers of a CheckBox that toggles Allow_X.  Now you know exactly when a settings value changes - the moment you trigger the write process e.g. inside the event handler. When you read the old value prior to overwriting it, you can display both in the UI.

Comment: @BionicCode ok I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

save the old setting in a variable ( oldValue ).
change the value in your settings file and then use MessageBox.show($"{oldValue} changed to {newValue}")

hope this is what you where looking for.

Comment: You did not answer as to how my application could "detect" when the setting(s) has changed and what setting/s has/have changed.